# How to set persistent low brightness in grub2 menu?

Tags: grub2

I have a Samsung laptop with ivy bridge Intel processor and Intel HD graphics. The brightness is controlled by `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` which accepts values from 0 to 4882. The standard way of Fn + F2/F3 to decrease/increase brightness also works when using supported desktop environment.

In POST screen and in grub menu, the brightness control with Fn + F2/F3 works but it doesn't persist on reboot. Every time the system boots, the POST screen, and the following grub menu always start in full brightness level.

The POST screen is as-is and I guess it cannot be tweaked. But is there a way to set a low brightness level in grub menu that persists on reboot, and maybe passes the same low brightness level to kernel on boot?